Proving that the $H_\infty$ norm for scalar transfer functions is a norm
I am trying to prove that the $H_\infty$ norm of a scalar transfer function, $h$ (with no poles on the imaginary axis), defined as
$$ ||h||_\infty := \sup_\omega |i\omega|$$
is a norm, i.e. it satisfies

$||h||_\infty = 0$ iff $h=0$
$||\alpha h||_\infty = |\alpha| ||h||_\infty$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$
$||h + g||_\infty \le ||h||_\infty + ||g||_\infty$

and in addition

$||h g||_\infty \le ||h||_\infty ||g||_\infty$

This is in fact Exercise 1.1 in Linear Robust Control by Green and Limeberg.
2, 3 and 4 are straightforward, and so is the if part of 1. I am having an issue with the only if part of 1.
$||h||_\infty = 0 \implies h = 0$ on the imaginary axis. Why does this mean that $h = 0$ everywhere? It seems that I am missing a simple logic, but not sure what it is.

What are the assumptions on $h$? Is it stable, rational?

I will use this answer to make a few corrections for common misconceptions. The first one is that the $H_\infty$ norm of a scalar transfer function $h$ is not defined as
$$
\sup_{\omega\in\mathbb{R}}|h(j\omega)|
$$
but as
$$
\sup_{s\in\mathbb{C},\Re[s]\ge0}|h(s)|.
$$
When the transfer does not have any poles in the closed right half-plane (stable), then the norm is finite.
Assuming further that this function $h$ is analytic on that domain (and its boundary), one can use a result called the maximum modulus principle that stipulates that the maximum modulus of an analytic function a certain domain can only be attained on the boundary of that domain.
Applying this result to the "correct" definition of the $H_\infty$-norm yields
$$
\sup_{s\in j\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}}|h(s)|
$$
where $j\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is the boundary of the closed right half-plane.
So, now if we assume that the tranfer function is stable and that its $H_\infty$-norm is zero, then we automatically have that $h\equiv0$. This will be the case for transfer functions representing stable linear time-invariant systems.
I am aware that it is often defined in the former way but this is a very misleading definition that missed the important part that $h$ needs to be stable. Moreover, that norm is for Hardy spaces of functions which are space of complex functions with a complex argument and this does not make much sense (mathematically speaking to define it this way) and that norm is usually named the $L_\infty$-norm of the transfer function $h$ and has other applications that the $H_\infty$-norm.
Finally, bear in mind that this is the first chapter of the book and that some corners have been cut. The proper definition for the $H_\infty$ is given later in the book.

I have typed this quickly and will come back later to polish. In the meantime, I am happy to hear about your comments and I will address them in the answer.

That clarifies a lot of things. I will also read it more carefully to make sure I am not missing anything. But one immediate question - if the transfer function is stable, and its $H_\infty$ norm is zero, it is clear that it is identically zero in the closed right half plane, but does this say that it is also zero in the open left half plane?

Yes, exactly. I will complete my answer once I have the chance to get to my computer.

In this chapter, the book only applies the $H_\infty$ norm to stable transfer functions, so it makes sense that in the interest of simplicity this early in the book, only the definition that applies for stable transfer functions is given (the maximum modulus principle is referenced as well). As you suggest, I will probably learn more of the subtleties as I progress through the book. My only remaining question is: If $h:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is zero in the closed right half plane, is it obvious that it is also zero in the open left half plane (without any other restrictions on $h$)?

I think I found an answer to my question in my last comment. If $h$ is meromorphic, which a rational transfer function is, then by the answer here, $h$ is zero in the open left half plane if it is zero in the closed right half plane. Is this correct?
